# Installing PyGame issues

Tags: python, pygame

I used to have PyGame installed on my PC but formatted my PC and now need it installed again. I have followed the same process as last time and have installed Python 3.3 and PyGame 3.3.0 off of GitBucket. I install PyThon to my only HDD as `Python33` and Pygame in a different file on my HDD as `PythonX`, but for some reason when entering `import pygame` but it just doesn't find the module. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? If windows, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

The pygame library must be in site-packages folder in Lib folder of your python folder.

It's better you don't personalize this kind of instalation. Why separate a language of its libraries?